# Regex for a sequence with an optional tail

Tags: regex

How to match a sequence with an optional tail of variable length.

For the example `requiredOptional` I would like to have an expression that matches `required`, `requiredO`, `requiredOp`, `requiredOpt`, `requiredOpti` ... `requiredOptional`.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Can you clarify a little? what will be the separator?

Comment: `re?q?u?i?r?e?O?p?t?i?o?n?a?l?` will have that effect, but it sounds like something I wouldn't use a regex for

Comment: `required(?:Optional|Optiona|Option|Optio|Opti|Opt|Op|O|)` or `required(?:O(?:p(?:t(?:i(?:o(?:n(?:al?)?)?)?)?)?)?)?`.

Answer (score -1):

How about

`Regex GetRegex(int length) {
            return new Regex(String.Format("requiredO{0}p{1}t{2}i{3}o{4}n{5}a{6}l{7}", length > 7 ? "?" : "", length > 6 ? "?" : "", length > 5 ? "?" : "", length > 4 ? "?" : "", length > 3 ? "?" : "", length > 2 ? "?" : "", length > 1 ? "?" : "", length > 0 ? "?" : ""), RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }`